# Why is my bcrypt authorization always return true

Tags: python, bcrypt

I setup a simple bcrpyt authorization on python. The hash matches every single time regardless of what the password is. I can't for the life of me figure out why it's doing this.

I for the life of me can't understand why it's doing this.

```
if bcrypt.hashpw(password, user.password) == user.password:
    uj = user_json(str(user.user_id), user.email, user.firstname, user.lastname, user.state, user.city)
    self.write(uj)
else:
    self.write(error_json(cna="cannot authorize user"))
```

Again regardless of the password I enter. The hash always returns something matching.

Comment: What do you mean by "returns something matching"?  You should print out the contents of `password`, `user.password` and `bcrypt.hashpw(password, user.password)` and see what actually is being passed around.  It could be a malformed `user.password`.

Comment: I was able to figure it out a while ago. Haven't logged in for a while, so I haven't noticed your response. It turns out I had a bad condition somewhere. It was a simple semantics error.